# How do I discover the valid lifetime and preferred lifetime of IPv6 addresses on OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, ipv6

On Linux, I can do `ip -6 addr list` and every address comes with a `valid_lft` and `preferred_lft`.  What is the OS X equivalent?  `ifconfig` doesn't include this information in its  output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the manual page of ifconfig](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ifconfig.8.html):

> If -L flag is supplied, address lifetime is displayed for IPv6 addresses, as time offset string.

The output looks like this:

```
en9: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=4<VLAN_MTU>
    ether 00:0e:ca:00:3d:0e 
    inet6 fe80::20e:caff:fe00:3d0e%en9 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xe 
    inet 192.168.178.21 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.178.255
    inet6 2001:db8:d:ff01:20e:caff:fe00:3d0e prefixlen 64 autoconf pltime 3385 vltime 6985 
    inet6 2001:db8:d:ff01:2559:b136:a7f2:67c0 prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary pltime 3385 vltime 6985 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex,flow-control>)
    status: active
```

Notice the `pltime` and `vltime` at the end of the `inet6` lines.

Comment: @SanderSteffann Good job, IOU1.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I even knew about this option at some point; I guess I must have searched the manpage for "valid" and "preferred" but not "lifetime"!